# Get-childitem filtered by lastwritetime

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have been having an issue trying to grab files of a certain age based on current date, all the code i'm finding says to use

```
|where {$_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).adddays(-7)}
```

but i am not getting any results, i tested the

```
(get-date).adddays(-7)
```

and it returned the correct date in a different format than the date returned from

```
get-childitem |select lastwritetime
```

but i cant seem to format the get-date within the string to match the format of the lastwritetime, is there something im missing? how can i get this to work?

Specifically im just testing to see how to filter by lastwritetime to make a backup script for practice, right now im trying to list all files older than X days with

```
get-childitem |where {$_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).adddays(-7)}
```

no errors but no results, and when i just list everything with lastwritetime there are obviously files within the parameters, so the format is all i can think of being the failure

Comment: I see no reason why this shouldn't work. Are you sure that there are files older then a week? Also why you don't specify a directory within your Get-ChildItem?

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are trying to gather the files *Older* than 7 days correct?  if so then you need to swap `-gt` for `-lt` since time in Windows is counted upwards so values larger than `(get-date).adddays(-7)` would indicate files that were written to in the last 7 days, rather than files that have not been written to.  Also keep in mind that Windows Metadata is horrifically unreliable(and user-changeable) so I wouldn't use this method for anything other than basic cleanup where 100% accuracy is not required.